# Delete within a function doesn't work in Javascript

Tags: javascript, object

My goal is to remove properties in an object with values greater than a given number "num" using a function. However, "delete" is not working. What would make delete not work in this situation, and is there a better solution?

```js
    function removeNumbersLargerThan(num, obj) {
      for(var key in obj){
        if(obj[key] > num){
          delete obj.key;
        }
      }
      return obj;
    }

    var obj = {
    a: 8,
    b: 2,
    c: 'montana'
    }
    removeNumbersLargerThan(5, obj);
    console.log(obj); // --> { b: 2, c: 'montana' }
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `delete obj[key];`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/208105/how-do-i-remove-a-property-from-a-javascript-object

Comment: `delete obj[key]`

Comment: mind that you can achieve the same goal returning a new object (without those properties). `delete` operator isn't performant and your function isn't pure.

Answer (score 0):

you are almost done.use same like if condition obj key match .`delete obj[key]`

```js
function removeNumbersLargerThan(num, obj) {
  for(var key in obj){
    if(obj[key] > num){
      delete obj[key];
    }
  }
  return obj;
}

var obj = {
a: 8,
b: 2,
c: 'montana'
}
removeNumbersLargerThan(5, obj)
console.log(obj); // --> { b: 2, c: 'montana' }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're flipping what property you're accessing.  You got it right the first time, but not the second:

```
function removeNumbersLargerThan(num, obj) {
  for(var key in obj){
    if(obj[key] > num){ // Correct!
      delete obj.key; // Should be obj[key] again
    }
  }
  return obj;
}
```

Otherwise you're going to delete the "key" property off of the `obj`

---

In other words, your loop isn't `delete`ing the property you actually want to `delete`.  It's just `delete`ing the `key` property on an Object:

```
// What you declare
let num = 5;
let obj = {
    key: "hello",
    keyToKill: 7,
    keyToLeaveAlone: 3
}

// Your initial loop to remove keys with value greater than a number
for (let key in obj) {
    // If I find a key whose value is greater than num
    if (obj[key] > num) {
        // Delete the "key" property
        delete obj.key;
    }
}

// The above will give you this:
let incorrect = {
    keyToKill: 7,
    keyToLeaveAlone: 3
}
```

If you want to delete the property whose value is greater than `num` you would do the following:

```
// If you do the following instead:
for (let key in obj) {
    // If I find a key whose value is greater than num
    if (obj[key] > num) {
        // Delete the property who's value is greater than num
        delete obj[key];
    }
}

// You'll get this
let correct = {
    key: "hello",
    keyToLeaveAlone: 3
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "Otherwise you're going to delete the "key" property off of the obj"?

Comment: @tskittles see my edit

Comment: Ahh makes sense. So when you're using dot notation, you're actually finding on the object a value with the key "key"

Comment: @tskittles Yes, `obj["key"] === obj.key` and `obj[key] !== obj.key`.  Note the quotes, they matter.

Answer (score 0):

You need the right [property accessor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors) with bracket notation for using a variable as value.

```
delete obj[key];
//        ^   ^
```

```js
function removeNumbersLargerThan(num, obj) {
    for (var key in obj) {
        if (obj[key] > num) {
            delete obj[key];
        }
    }
    return obj;
}

var obj = { a: 8, b: 2, c: 'montana' };

removeNumbersLargerThan(5, obj);
console.log(obj); // { b: 2, c: 'montana' }
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
    function removeNumbersLargerThan(num, obj) {
      for(var key in obj){
        if(obj[key] > num){
          delete obj.key;
        }
      }
      return obj;
    }

    var obj = {
    a: 8,
    b: 2,
    c: 'montana'
    }
    removeNumbersLargerThan(5, obj);
    console.log(obj); // --> { b: 2, c: 'montana' }
```

```js
  function removeNumbersLargerThan(num, obj) {
      for(var key in obj){
        if(obj[key] > num){
          delete obj[key];
        }
      }
      return obj;
    }

    var obj = {
    a: 8,
    b: 2,
    c: 'montana'
    }
    removeNumbersLargerThan(5, obj);
    console.log(obj); // --> { b: 2, c: 'montana' }
```